# chsh: PAM: Permission denied

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, zsh

I've seen the other threads on this, but nothing as specific and explicit as mine.

I'm trying change my Shell from standard Bash to ZSH.

Using `chsh -s /usr/bin/zsh` gets me the following error: `chsh: PAM: Permission denied`.

`usr/bin/zsh` shows up in `/etc/shells`. Using `sudo` works, but it seems like the command just doesn't work, as upon reboots I still got bash.

The strange thing is, in `etc/passwd` zsh does show up for root.

I've already changed `/etc/pam.d/chsh` to the following:

```
# This will not allow a user to change their shell unless
# their current one is listed in /etc/shells. This keeps
# accounts with special shells from changing them.
auth       sufficient   pam_shells.so

# This allows root to change user shell without being
# prompted for a password
auth        sufficient  pam_rootok.so
```

but alas it still doesn't work. Any pointers?

edit:

The output of `ls -l $(which chsh)`

```
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 53040 May 28  2020 /usr/bin/chsh
```

Comment: *"Using sudo works"* using sudo how, exactly? there's a difference between `sudo chsh -s /usr/bin/zsh` and `sudo chsh -s /usr/bin/zsh username`. BTW does `/usr/bin/chsh` have the setuid bit?

Comment: @steeldriver Good point. I used `sudo chsh -s /usr/bin/zsh` - what's the difference between the two? And I'm afraid I'd need more elaboration on the setuid part.

Comment: If you don't supply a username, it will change the shell for the current user - in the case of `sudo`, that's root. For the setuid bit, please [edit] your question to include the output of `ls -l $(which chsh)`

Comment: @steeldriver I've edited the question. As for the user: that shouldn't be of any concern, as it's just for my local and I'm root.

Comment: It's not a matter of *concern* - there's a difference between *being* root (`uid = 0`) and being able to become root (via sudo). Is the pam.d file really named `csh` rather than `chsh` or was that a typo?

Comment: @steeldriver Damn, busted! That was a typo.